# Visibliy control using IIFE

Tags: javascript

I have created following three modules. The question is, just by using IIFE ( without using modular library like common.js, require.js etc ) how to design this in a way that only module2 is visible to module3, and only module1 should be visible to module2.

Q2. How to avoid having module1 and module2 going into global scope, since i need to expose ONLY mondule3 which will be accessible from html ?

## module1.js

```
var module1 = (function(){
  var  module1Msg = "This is Module 1";

  return {
    module1Msg:module1Msg
  };
})();
```

## module2.js

```
var module2 = (function(){
  var  module2Msg = module1.module1Msg +" - "+" This is Module 2";

  return {
        module2Msg:module2Msg
  };
})();
```

## module3.js

```
var module3 = (function(){
  var  module3Msg = module2.module2Msg +" - " +" This is Module 3";

  return {
    module3Msg:module3Msg
  };
})();
```

and using those modules from following html file

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Module Experiment</title>
<script src="module1.js"></script>
<script src="module2.js"></script>
<script src="module3.js"></script>

<script>
    alert(module3.module3Msg);

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="display"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are asking for AMD functionality, but don't want to use an AMD library. Why not? In all cases, there will be some overhead involved, whether you use a client-side AMD library, a server-side bundler like browserify, or roll your own solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could do the module loading yourself. You can make use of the module loading by creating a function that loads the javascript files for you, you would no longer have your script tags inside your html (except for your starting app).

As an example, you could do something similar like:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Module Experiment</title>
<script>
    'use strict';
    var scriptBase = './js/';
    var scriptcounter = 0;

    function require(arr, callback) {
        var requested = 0, loaded = 0;
        arr.forEach(function(script) {
            var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
            scriptTag.id = 'myscript' + (++scriptcounter);
            requested++;
            scriptTag.addEventListener('load', function() {
                loaded++;
                if (loaded === requested) {
                    callback();
                }
            });
            scriptTag.src = scriptBase + script + '.js';
            document.head.appendChild(scriptTag);
        });
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        require(['module1'], function() {
            require(['module2'], function() {
                require(['module3'], function() {
                    // everything loaded
                    console.log('I can call module3 here');
                    var el = document.getElementById('display');
                    el.innerHTML = module3.module3Msg;
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="display"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

in this case the require takes an array and calls the callback when the script is loaded. At that time, you can run your code, or you can choose to get some other file to do more work.

The function could also be called like `require(['module1', 'module2', 'module3'], function() { ... })` but you might have a problem that `module2` gets loaded before `module1` which would result in a missing reference error, so, that's why I wrote the require code above in 3 different require statements. (this you can still have in your current setup. It is unsure what script will be received online the first, so it could be your application would work 90 % and give some difficult to reproduce errors the other 10 %.

You could make it yourself easier by at least "defining" your modules in a shared class and then inject some classes based on their string id, but I guess this is out of the scope of your question.

Comment: Excellent, i like the way you explained. Actually i know the best way to use either common or require.js to solve this problem but, i was just wondering how to solve the problem with just plain java script. and you did it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The pattern you are using requires that each module place anything that it wants to be accessible from another module in the global scope.

The revealing module pattern lets you restrict a variable so it accessible only to the module itself. It doesn't let you limit variables to other specific modules.

---

You could restrict a module by placing its entire definition in the `()` at the end of another module (and capturing it in an argument), but then you couldn't keep them in separate files.

Answer (score -1):

Just pass reference to the module as parameter to the specific iife. Pass module2 to module3 as parameter and do the same with module1 and module2

Comment: How? They are in different files. You'd have to make the value a global before you can pass it to another module, at which point it is already available to all modules.